# Setting each cell in its own group

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My UITableViewCells take up the full viewing area.  I'd like to use a grouped table so the cells appear to have rounded corners.  Right now, if I set the number of sections to something greater than one, I get the number of sections in grouped style but all the cells repeat in each section.  How do I setup the table so each cell is in a section?

Also, is it possible to programmatically set the table style to grouped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question:

```
tableView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
```

Or, if you're creating it programmatically:

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

For your first question, I assume you are setting up your cells something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    ...
    setupCell(cell,indexPath.row);
    return cell;
}
```

Where setupCell is something that checks the index and sets the cell accordingly.  The IndexPath, however, tells you which row *in which section* to set up.

I also assume that you're returning the full number of rows in the function

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Where you should only be returning 1, since you want exactly 1 row in each section.

Then when setting up your cell, you'd want to check the `indexPath.section` instead of the `indexPath.row`.  Rows are zero-based by section, so the calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will have index paths that look like this:

Section Row
0, 0
1, 0
2, 0

Whereas originally, when you had only one section, it would have been:
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2

And what you're seeing right now, since you return the same number of rows as sections is:
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2

1, 0
1, 1
1, 2

2, 0
2, 1
2, 2

Answer (score 1):

actually, you can't do this:

`tableView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;`

because style is a readonly property.