# How to split up pList alphabetically into groups like iOS contacts

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios4

I have been trying to separate a pList that I have already alphabetized into the TableView. For example, when the names switch from A to B, I want the fancy grouped table format to separate A from B.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Here is my code, that I have doing the sorting.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kEMPLOYEE_PLIST];

NSMutableArray *countries = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

// Now the array holds NSDictionaries, sort 'em:
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"FullName" ascending:YES] autorelease];
sortedCountries = [[countries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]] retain];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this potentially related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962217/setting-each-cell-in-its-own-group), but basically what you need to do is have each letter (or group) be a section.

First you'll need to specify your table is grouped (whether in Interface Builder or via UITableView's [`- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/initWithFrame:style:) method, specifying [`UITableViewStyleGrouped`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewStyleGrouped) as the style.

Then you'll want to implement:

UITableViewDataSource's

[`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:) method

and

[`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:)

and of course UITableViewDataSource's

[`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) method.

In this last method, you can look at indexPath.section to get the letter of the alphabet you want to return and indexPath.row to return the Nth entry that exists for that letter (group).

Is this enough to work with for now?

Comment: so i have all the methods setup, and i have it displaying in the group format. The problem is that it is one big list. so how would i tell Xcode that i want to split on each letter, and where would i do that?

Comment: `numberOfSectionsInTableView` should return 27 (for 27 letters in the English language alphabet... you might want to change this if you'll be using different alphabets).  `numberOfRowsInSection` should return the correct number of entries under each letter.  It sounds like the real work will come with how you read your NSArray. I might re-do it as a NSDictionary where each key is a letter and each value is a sorted array.

Comment: this is what i needed, it took me a while to figure it out. This was what lead me to the right answer.

Comment: this also helped me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051009/how-to-create-sectioned-grouped-table-view-alphabetically